# How long do eggs last at room temperature?

Tags: eggs, salmonella

Eggs that were never refrigerated and placed in an ACed room at a constant temperature of 77-78f (25-26c), how long before they start to go bad?

Comment: Washed or unwashed? Unwashed eggs last a lot longer than washed eggs.

Comment: My unwashed European eggs last weeks for sure, sometimes months.